# Cast EF DBquery to Viewmodel - Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a Entity Framework query who group the result, I want to pass it to view, but I cant cast it correct to the viewmodel! (I want to show the result in a grid in the view)

If I use this cast

```
 viewModel.Groupeds = (IEnumerable<Grouped>) result;
```

I get these error
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType4`2[System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.Int32]]' to type

How should I cast it?

```
public ActionResult Show(int? id)
    {
       IEnumerable<dynamic> result = db.StatData
             .GroupBy(k => new { k.QuestId, k.OptionId })
             .Select(c => new
             {
                 OptionId = c.Select(q => q.OptionId).FirstOrDefault(),
                 Counted = c.Select(q => q.id).Count(),
             });

             var viewModel = new StatsView();
             viewModel.Groupeds = (IEnumerable<Grouped>) result;
    return View(viewModel);
}

public class StatsView
{
    public IEnumerable<Grouped> Groupeds { get; set; }
}


public partial class Grouped
{
    public Nullable<int> Counted { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> OptionId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code creates an `IEnumerable` of anonymous types, you should create `IEnumerable` of `Grouped` result. Note that although the anonymous type you created and the `Grouped` have the same properties, but they are different types and cannot cast them to each other.

```
public ActionResult Show(int? id)
{
   //defining result as var is sufficient 
   var result = db.StatData
         .GroupBy(k => new { k.QuestId, k.OptionId })
         .Select(c => new Grouped//<<-here
         {
             OptionId = c.Select(q => q.OptionId).FirstOrDefault(),
             Counted = c.Select(q => q.id).Count(),
         }).ToList();//commit the query
         var viewModel = new StatsView();
         viewModel.Groupeds = result;//No need for casting
   return View(viewModel);
}
```

It is better to commit the query (i.e by `ToList()`) before sending it to the view, because if the context disposes, before the view generation, it causes an error.

Comment: I cant compile it if I change, get error

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: int? Optionid, int Counted>>' 
to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Boilerplate.Web.ViewModel.Grouped>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: did you changed `.Select(c => new Grouped//<<-here` this part of your code?